# What kind of equipment do I need to turn dried chilli flakes into powder?

Tags: equipment

What kind of equipment do I Need to turn dried chilli flakes into powder?
[image: Chilli flakes => Chilli powder]

Answer (score 5):

You need a [bladed spice grinder](https://www.seriouseats.com/2018/02/the-best-spice-grinders.html), also branded as bladed coffee grinders.

To have a consistent result, sift the result.

Comment: This is what I use and it works very efficiently. Note, that I never use the grinder for anything other than peppers.

Answer (score 2):

Not long ago I managed to do that with just a regular blender. Put chili flakes in and whirl until powdered. Do not remove the lid before chili powder settles. Then gently sift for very consistent result.

I wouldn't really recommend using a coffee grinder because that would bring too much heat in.

Comment: I used a blender to make chili powder out of a pound of de-seeded, dried, Hatch/Anaheim type peppers last fall. For smaller amounts, a spice grinder would do. You are likely to hurt the bearings of a modern superspeed blender (20Krpm+) if you try to use one for this purpose; too much heat buildup.

Answer (score 2):

**I would use my mortar and pestle.**

[image: mortar and pestle]
[source](https://www.amazon.com/s?bbn=16439881&rh=n%3A1055398%2Cn%3A%211063498%2Cn%3A284507%2Cn%3A289754%2Cn%3A289779%2Cn%3A16439881%2Cp_n_feature_keywords_two_browse-bin%3A7022597011&dc&fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1577310778&rnid=5379566011&ref=lp_16439881_nr_p_n_feature_keywords_2)

I have been thru many coffee bean grinders.  I still use the mortar and pestle I bought in 1992.  It is easy to get the spices out.  It is easy to clean.  It is easy to control the grind.  If spices are wet, or greasy, it works.  It was cheap.

It is old school.

Comment: You certainly have my respect. I love my mortar and pestle, but there are either techniques I'm weak on or grinding pepper flakes into powder with one is both difficult and exhausting. (I have done it once or twice. But I'd rather not do it again.)

Answer (score -2):

If you want to turn flakes to powder, you need this:

[Electric Herbal Coffee Bean Grinder Machine Spices Cereals Crusher Dry Food Grinder Mill Kitchen Grinding](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000494352084.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.206f296alw5cFN&s=p&algo_pvid=cac06f4d-fba3-46fe-9865-cd1429e2d39f&algo_expid=cac06f4d-fba3-46fe-9865-cd1429e2d39f-1&btsid=37758283-775c-48e4-bb06-9ce3a5cb5330&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_8,searchweb201603_53)

Comment: Without a “why you should use this”, this is a) a link-only answer and b) pretty close to spam. And are you sure that this is appropriate for a domestic scale?

Comment: The capacity of this machine is only 800grams, hardly enough for commercial use. It can mill cereals, nuts and of course, herbs. And the reason is that the rotational speed is more than 20,000rpm.

Comment: And *that* is exactly the *why* that would be good in an answer. Not „use this“, but „the properties of a suitable tool are.., e.g. (link)“.